What is the likelihood of recovering full costs of winning an expectation damages case?
Suppose Bob from this question hired a lawyer and won the case against the seller in England (the seller was stubborn enough not to settle).
How likely is that Bob will also be awarded 100% of the legal costs and disbursements?

canada
It is extremely unlikely for a plaintiff to be awarded full legal costs (also known as "solicitor and client costs" or "full indemnity  basis") and disbursements.
Instead, a successful plaintiff is normally awarded costs on a tariff scale based on the complexity of the litigation steps, often offsetting a portion, but not all, of the total legal costs. All reasonable disbursements are also generally covered.

It’s a possibility
Costs are complicated and, ultimately, discretionary.
The general rule in common law jurisdictions outside the USA is that costs follow the event. That is, the successful party is awarded costs on a party-party (i.e. at scheduled rates) basis. But there are lots of reasons for deviating from the rule. Party-party rates generally cover 50-60% of the actual costs (YMMD).
To get an indemnity basis order requires:

A hopeless case
Abuse of process
Unreasonable conduct or “relevant delinquency”
Fraud and misconduct
Offers of compromise and Calderbank letters
Avoidance of arbitration or dispute resolution clauses

Notwithstanding, the costs must still be reasonable. Engaging a King’s Counsel at $20,000 a day for a $500 case would not be reasonable.

Why are "offers of compromise and Calderbank letters" on the list along with clearly reprehensible stuff? Are they frowned upon?

@Greendrake why don’t you ask the question?

The level of my curiosity in the answer is below the threshold for bothering to ask a whole separate question.

@Greendrake I encourage you to do so - they’re actually quite a significant part of civil litigation

Why encourage? Do you worry about my legal competency? Otherwise, if you want to answer such a question, you can ask it yourself.
